# How to combine exact phrase and partial matches in searchkick

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I need to perform a search compound of exact matches and *regular* matches, like:
`honda toyota "hybrid car"` and I want to match either `honda` and `toyota` with `hybrid car`. Also I would like to provide this syntax to the user, allowing to place the exact terms inside double quotes.

I've seen the searchkick documentation and only found how can I search for an exact expression, not a combination of both:

`User.search "fresh honey", match: :phrase`

How can I do it?